# Inserting a pair into multimap on osx

Tags: c++, macos, insert, multimap

I need some help! I'm using a multimap to map the indices of musical notes, so I can access them by a string name of the note, as well as the int value. However, the code works perfectly fine on Windows, but when moving it to OSX (the latest version). I get a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" error anytime insert is used.

[Runtime Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwmdi.png)

I know I'm not using best method to insert the notes and indices into the multimap, but I intend to rewrite it.

I've tried several method to get it working, but no success. Here the code.

Header

```
class zelmNote
{
private:
    static bool bNoteMapped;
    static multimap<int, string> noteToName;
    static multimap<string, int> nameToNote;

    static void mapNotes();

public:
    zelmNote();
};
```

.cpp

```
multimap<int, string> zelmNote::noteToName;
multimap<string, int> zelmNote::nameToNote;

void zelmNote::mapNotes()
{
    bNoteMapped = true;
    int i = 9;
    string noteName = "";
    /*intToNote.insert(pair<int, string>(8, "G#"));
    noteToInt.insert(pair<string, int>("G#", 8));
    intToNote.insert(pair<int, string>(8, "Ab"));
    noteToInt.insert(pair<string, int>("G#", 8));*/
    //Do natural notes
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'G'; c++)
    {
        noteName = ofToString(c);
        noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(i, noteName));
        nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>(noteName, i));
        if (i == 11)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
        else if (i == 4)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if ((i != 11) || (i != 4))
        {
            i += 2;
        }
    }


    //Do sharps
    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(0, "B#"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("B#", 0));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(1, "C#"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("C#", 1));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(3, "D#"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("D#", 3));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(4, "D##"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("D##", 4));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(5, "E#"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("E#", 5));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(6, "F#"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("F#", 6));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(8, "G#"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("G#", 8));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(10, "A#"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("A#", 10));


    //Do flats
    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(11, "Cb"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("Cb", 11));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(0, "Dbb"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("Dbb", 0));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(1, "Db"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("Db", 1));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(3, "Eb"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("Eb", 3));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(4, "Fb"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("Fb", 4));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(6, "Gb"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("Gb", 6));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(8, "Ab"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("Ab", 8));

    noteToName.insert(pair<int, string>(10, "Bb"));
    nameToNote.insert(pair<string, int>("Bb", 10));
}

zelmNote::zelmNote()
{
    if (!bNoteMapped)
    {
        mapNotes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Non compiling example. Recommend beating it into an [mcve].

Comment: Is this the segment of the code that's causing errors? It looks perfectly good to me.

Comment: The valuable part of your error has been cropped of. Please consider including it as text.

Comment: This code is part of a class `zelmNote`.  Since it is part of a class, you must have created instances of this class somewhere.  We have no idea if the instance of `zelmNote` you are accessing is valid.  If it isn't valid, then the members of the `zelmNote` instance are not valid, including the maps.  Thus you need to post where, when, and how you're creating these `zelmNote` instances.

Comment: Thanks for feedback guys, I was going edit the thread with the full code, but last comment made me realise what I was doing wrong - I was calling the private static mapNotes() from the constructor of a new zelmMap object with boolean checking if it been run before. OSX seem to doesn't like the static being called there, when moving mapNotes() to a public function and calling from the parent class's constructor it seems to work!

Comment: I added the code causing the error for future reference

Comment: @ZacharySnow *OSX seem to doesn't like the static being called there, when moving mapNotes() to a public function and calling from the parent class's constructor it seems to work!* -- Sounds like undefined behavior due to static initialization order not being deterministic across modules, and you're just lucky the program "works" in another environment.

Comment: Hey, I did some reading on undefined behaviour and I think you’re right. The other static calls for Interval, Chord and Scale are called from a parent class, but when I wrote Note it didn’t exist. So are you telling me that because the statics aren’t initialised when the constructor is called, it can’t use the container? I thought static declarations are initialised when the file is read.... Sorry I’m self-taught (as many are) could recommend any books that expand on the terminology?

Comment: @ZacharySnow -- Did you [read this?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)

Comment: No I haven't, I'll give the whole FAQ a read when I get minute, thanks!